# ASP.NET clearing application cache running on a different server programmatically

Tags: asp.net, caching

I'm trying to clear cache of an application programmatically from a different server. I've seen many posts on clearing it from within the application but not for something like this.
If you touch the `Web.Config` file, it will recycle app pool causing app to clear. Assuming the host application has access, I could programmatically do that. But was wondering if there is a better way to just clear all cache items and not restart the app pool.

Comment: Your best bet would likely be to create an API that clears the cache entries on the application whose cache is to be refreshed (so you have access to the AppDomain), then call that API externally.  Though this question is a bit broad to be answered succinctly.  Are you looking for a code sample?

Comment: Yes, a code example would be ideal. I like your idea but that requires a extra app to be created; was hoping for a more direct solution (even if a little hacky as that will do for this purpose). But if nothing else works out, I will take the route you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are a couple of points to consider when clearing the WHOLE cache:

1. If you are storing things in Cache, you hopefully have some kind of synchronization method .  That being the case, removing ALL things could cause some issues (locking, slow performance, race conditions).
2. Accessing an application's cache from an external AppDomain as far as I know isn't possible (Some chief reasons for this among others I'm sure are synchronization and security issues).

That being said, if you wanted to clear EVERY entry in cache (assuming you are using the `System.Web.Caching` methods to do so) you could introduce some code similar to this:

```
List<string> keys = new List<string>();

IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext()){
    keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());
} // end while
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++) {
    Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
}  // end for loop
```

You could then expose the above code via a url (ex: `http://example.com/admin/refresh-cache`).

This would allow you to clear the cache programmatically from another application or batch file, or you could access it directly from the URL.

To elaborate more on the first bullet above, the .NET caching mechanisms (of which there are many flavors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357(v=vs.110).aspx) all have their own built in expiration functionality.  If you find yourself in a place where you want to clear the entire cache it may be an indication that you should either A) Improve your cache retention values or B) recycle the application pool as this will ensure a safer transition for users of the application.  Remember that whatever is placing items in cache when an application is running **will likely still be attempting to do so when you are clearing everything**.

---

Another option to consider would be to use a cache management solution such as AppFabric (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @xDaevax. This is what I was envisioning too - to get all keys and clear them. But I guess will need to write a service to do that. Sometimes there are some changes made in the database and those need to take effect immediately. That's when I usually clear cache. Ideally I should find the exact items that should be cleared for that purpose but it works OK to clear out all for my purpose at the moment.